# react app built by `npm run build` is not loading image source when deployed to App Engine

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-app-engine, npm, webpack

I have react front end app, which loads `logo.png` in `Header.tsx` as img element like below;

```
<img className={classes.headerLogo}
     src={'logo.png'}
     alt={"MY_LOGO"}/>
```

And directory structure is like this;

```
├── header
│   ├── Header.tsx
│   └── logo.png
```

When I run `npm start` it will load `logo.png` as expected, while it won't when I run `npm run build` and deploy output to Google's App Engine.
[image]

As deploy configuration file about App Engine, I have `app.yaml` like below;

```
runtime: nodejs12

automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 4
  min_instances: 1

default_expiration: '10d'

handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: build/static
  - url: /(.*\.(json|ico|js|png))$
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.(json|ico|js)$
  - url: /public
    static_dir: public
  - url: .*
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
    expiration: '0s'
```

I have checked other similar posts about image loading with `npm run build` and App Engine, but they could not solve my issue.
Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is in your `app.yaml`, in the handler section you have this:

```
- url: /(.*\.(json|ico|js|png))$
  static_files: build/\1
  upload: build/.*\.(json|ico|js)$
```

The problem here is that you are handling `.png` files in the url, but not in the upload value, where it's missing, if you were to change it to the following it will fix it:

```
- url: /(.*\.(json|ico|js|png))$
  static_files: build/\1
  upload: build/.*\.(json|ico|js|png)$
```

Comment: How poor.... thank you so much! Your answer solved my issue like a magic.